# loading an xml in web apps directory from a library dll

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, server.mappath

my web application has an xml file here:

```
/files/xml/test.xml
```

I need to load a XDocument from within a class library project, how will I reference the xml?  I don't want to pass any path parameters to this method.

I want to assume the location is fixed at `/files/xml/test.xml`.

**How can I load a XDocument know this?**

I don't seem to have access to server.mappath either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never assume locations. Your function really **should** take a file path, then from your Web Context, you call `server.mappath` to produce the correct path to load.

If you want to fix something, load it in as a resource constant or a const variable.

```
public static class Globals
{
   public const string TestPath = "/files/xml/text.xml";
}
```